# how to distort an image with jquery

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

I want to make a carousel/slider that is similar to this one: [carousel](http://codecanyon.net/item/icarousel/2527180)  The problem I am having is the distortion of the image.  Is this possible with jquery or do i need to do something different with the whole idea?  I haven't started the coding process yet because i really don't even know where to begin.  Any help would be awesome.

Comment: you could try using CSS filters

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CSS filters to achieve the same effect. Here's a great write up on the subject 
http://davidwalsh.name/css-filters

Comment: That was interesting.  i was looking for something that would give me the ability to change the dimensions of the image without having to make a bunch of images in photoshop.